# finding dual basis of vector space of polynomial degree less than or equal to 3

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $V = P(3)$, Describe a basis for $V^*$ and express the linear functional $f : V \to \Bbb R$ given by $f\left(a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0\right) = 2a_3 + a_2 - 5a_0$ as a linear combination of the basis you found for $V^*$.

I am struggling to find the basis for $V^*$, I know that the standard basis for $P(3)$ is $\left\{1, x, x^2, x^3\right\}$ and then the basis for $V^*$ is $f\left\{1, x, x^2, x^3\right\}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a basis for the dual space $V^*$, $\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}$  such that $$f_i(v_j)=\begin{cases}1 \ \ \ \mbox{if} \ \ i=j \\0 \ \ \  \mbox{if} \ \ i\ne j \end{cases}. $$ As a small hint, try using a combination of derivatives and evaluation maps.

Comment: would the dual basis also be {1,x,x2,x3} ?

Comment: @user77558 Not exactly.  If $f\in V^*$, then $f$ is a linear functional, a  linear function that goes from $V$ to the field $F$ the vector space is over (in our case, $\mathbb{R}$). So $\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}$ need to be functions that spit out real numbers. As another hint, let $f_1$ be the map that takes a polynomial and evaluates it at $0$: $$f_1\left(p(x)\right)=p(0)$$ What do the basis elements of $P(3)$ map to under this functional?