# Linear functionals and dual bases

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, functions, polynomials

[image]

How do I tackle this question? I am a little hazy on linear functionals and integral signs.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $B := \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$. You have to find a basis $B^*= \{ L_1, L_2, L_3\}$ for the dual space $V^{*}$ such that
$$L_i(v_j) = \begin{cases}1 & \mbox{if } i=j \\ 0 & \mbox{if } i \neq j \end{cases}.$$

Hint: Try combinations of evaluations, derivatives and integrals.

The following two subjects might be helpful:

[Finding a dual basis for the vector space of polynomials degree less than or equal to 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575950/finding-a-dual-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-polynomials-degree-less-than-or-equ)

[finding dual basis of vector space of polynomial degree less than or equal to 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389920/finding-dual-basis-of-vector-space-of-polynomial-degree-less-than-or-equal-to-3)

After that write $L$ in terms of $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$.

Answer (score 1):

An easier answer: define $f_0,f_1,f_2$ to be the dual basis to $1,x,x^2$.  So, $f_i$ are linear functionals with
$$
f_i(x^j) = \begin{cases}1 & i = j \\ 0 & i \neq j\end{cases}
$$
We note that $f_0,f_1,f_2$ is a basis of the dual space, so that
$$
L = a_0f_0 +  a_1 f_1 + a_2 f_2
$$
for some scalars $a_i$.  In fact, we may state that for $j = 0,1,2$,
$$
L(x^j) = a_0f_0(x^j) +  a_1 f_1(x^j) + a_2 f_2(x^j) = a_j
$$
So, we conclude that
$$
a_0 = L(1), \quad a_1 = L(x), \quad a_2 = L(x^2)
$$